# Send an email using PHP, HTML and JSON

Tags: php, html, json, email, html-email

I want to send an email automatically using some static and some dynamic data. So this is the process:

1. In my main `*.php` I´m fetching the data from my ddbb and
   creating the JSON.
2. I´m sending this JSON to another `*.php` to manage this data an
   insert it in my `<html>` (Second `*.php`).
3. Again in the first *.php I´m preparing the mail options and sending
   it. Here is the code.

**`first.php`**

```
...   
$query1= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='".$field1."'");
$row1= mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
$data_row1[] = $row1;

$query2= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='".$field2."'");
$row2= mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
$data_row2[] = $row2;

$data = array(
    "data_row1" => $data_row1,
    "data_row2" => $data_row2
);

$json_data = json_encode($data);
$url = 'https://webpage.com/folder/second.php?';
$variables = 'data='.$json_data;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $variables);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$email_text = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Then, in the `second.php`:**

```
<?php
    $result = $_GET['data'];
    $data = json_decode($result);

    $row_data1[] = $data['row_data1'];
    $row_data2[] = $data['row_data2'];
    $name= $row_data1['var1']." ".$row_data1['var2'];
    $city= $row_data2['var2'];
    ...
?>
<html>
    ... Some html printing the dynamic values using <?php echo $name; ?>
</html>
```

**Finally, again in the `first.php`**

```
...
$to = $destionation_email;
$subject = "The email subject";
$headers = "From: noreply@webpage.com".strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $email_text, $headers);
```

But my problem is that `second.php` is not fetching the JSON and the email is only showing the static `html`, without any data.

Any solution to fetch the JSON from the `second.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I´ve decided to do everything in the same `*.php`, so I don´t need to send and receive anything.

The way I´m creating the HTML with dynamic values is:

```
$email_text = 
    '<html>
        <body>
        ...
            <strong>'.$variable1.'</strong>
        </body>
    </html>';
```

It´s a pretty long HTML message, but I wasn´t able to do using the other way. I will keep this question opened just in case someone knows another method to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<php echo $first_variable ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo $first_variable; ?>
```

Comment: The first "?" is there but not the ";". I will try ;)

Comment: It wasn't there when I posted it, assuming you meant it's in the actual code.

Comment: Yes, it was in my code but here. Otherwise it is not working adding the ";".